# Traversing worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks to @Tim WIlliams I have the following code that generates insert statements. However, when I add the following sub to call it to travserse the workbook, it still picks up just the active sheet. What am I doing wrong?

```
 Sub WorksheetLoop()

   Dim WS_Count As Integer
   Dim I As Integer
   Dim current As Worksheet
   ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
   ' workbook.
   WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

   ' Begin the loop.
   For Each current In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


      Call DoSQL

      'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

   Next

   End Sub

   Sub DoSQL()
   myfile = "test.txt"
   fnum = FreeFile()
   Open myfile For Output As fnum

    Const SQL = "insert into <tbl>(<cols>) values (<vals>)"
    Dim dictSQL As Object, rw1 As Range, r As Long, rowSQL
    Dim sht As Worksheet, k, c As Range
    Dim cols, vals

    'Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set rw1 = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    Set dictSQL = tableDict(rw1)

    r = 2

    Do While sht.Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""

        For Each k In dictSQL
            rowSQL = Replace(SQL, "<tbl>", k)
            cols = ""
            vals = ""

            For Each c In dictSQL(k).Cells
               cols = cols & IIf(Len(cols) > 0, ",", "") & Split(c.Value, ".")(1)
               vals = vals & IIf(Len(vals) > 0, ",", "") & _
                             "'" & Trim(sht.Cells(r, c.Column).Value) & "'"
            Next c

            rowSQL = Replace(rowSQL, "<cols>", cols)
            rowSQL = Replace(rowSQL, "<vals>", vals)
            Debug.Print rowSQL
            Print #fnum, rowSQL
        Next k

        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Close #fnum

   End Sub

   Function tableDict(rw As Range)
    Dim rv As Object, tbl
    Set rv = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rw.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 And InStr(c.Value, ".") > 0 Then
            tbl = Split(c.Value, ".")(0) 'table name
            If rv.exists(tbl) Then
                Set rv(tbl) = Application.Union(c, rv(tbl))
            Else
                rv.Add tbl, c
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    Set tableDict = rv
    End Function
```

Comment: I already edited my original answer to add the looping...

Comment: I solved this. I was missing
 For Each current In Application.Worksheets
   current.Activate

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [Ripster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15096459/698590), you could pass the `current` sheet to the `DoSQL` Sub...

```
For Each current In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    DoSQL(current)
Next
```

And change your Sub to match...

```
Sub DoSQL(sht As Worksheet)
    myfile = "test.txt"
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open myfile For Output As fnum

    Const SQL = "insert into <tbl>(<cols>) values (<vals>)"
    Dim dictSQL As Object, rw1 As Range, r As Long, rowSQL
    Dim k, c As Range
    Dim cols, vals

    'Your code continues...
```

**As a side note:** Generally speaking, it's not a good idea to use `ActiveSheet`/`ActiveWorkbook`, since this can get mucked up if your code activates different objects as it progresses. To avoid this problem, you should explicitly set each sheet as an object (not using `ActiveSheet`!). 'ThisWorkbook' will ensure that the code is only running on the workbook from which the code was called, which is a step in the right direction over `ActiveWorkbook`.

**Another side note:** You should also get into the habit of explicitly declaring your variables. If no data type is specified, the default `Variant` type is used, which will take up more memory than your simpler types (`Integer`, etc.). Also, dimming more than one variable on a line is permissible, but each one has to have it's on type specification.

In other words, the following (from your code) would produce 2 variables, one (c) of the type `Range`, the other (k) a Variant.

```
Dim k, c As Range
```

**Lastly (then I'll get off my soap box):** It is a very good idea to use `Option Explicit` (just add that to the top of all your modules) to enforce the declaration of variables. Failure to do so can lead to a much tougher time tracking down certain errors that wouldn't necessarily be caught until runtime.

Comment: +1 for not selecting, not using activesheet/activeworkbook, and for explaining that k is a variant.

Answer (score 0):

You never change sheets in your for statement so the DoSQL sub always pulls the data from the same sheet. You either need to select the current sheet in your loop or pass current to the DoSQL sub for use.

This should fix the problem:

```
   For Each current In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      Current.Select
      Call DoSQL
      'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
   Next
```